# Inverse of a Bounded Linear Map between Banach Spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $S,T:X \rightarrow Y$ be bounded linear maps between Banach spaces $X$ and $Y$. Suppose $T$ is a bijection. Prove that there exists $\delta>0$ depending only on $T$ such that $||S-T||<\delta$ implies that $S$ is a bijection.

Edit: I have found the answer to my question and will be posting it here so that the question can be closed.

We let $S=(T(\mathbb{I}−T^{−1}(T−S))$. We let $A=T^{−1}(T−S)$ and then we can use the fact that $(\mathbb{I}−A)$ is invertible for $||A||<1$. So now we only need $||S−T||<1/||T^{−1}||$ so that $||A||=||T^{−1}(T-S)||<1$. The quantity $(1/||T^{−1}||)$ will be the $\delta$ mentioned in the problem. So now we have $S=T(\mathbb{I}−A)$. $T$ is invertible, $(\mathbb{I}−A)$ is invertible, therefore $S$ is invertible.

Comment: What have you done so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I have no idea where to start.

Comment: Are you sure that it is not given that $S$ is surjective?

Comment: It is not given that $S$ is surjective. But I may have found the answer already. We let $S=(T(\mathbb{I}-T^{-1}(T-S)))$. We let $A=T^{-1}(T-S)$ and then we can use the fact that $(\mathbb{I}-A)$ is invertible for $||A||<1$. So now we only need $||S-T||<1/||T^{-1}||$ so that $||A||=||T^{-1}(S-T)||<1$. $1/||T^{-1}||$ will be the $\delta$ in the problem.

So now we have $S=(T(\mathbb{I}-A))$.  $T$ is invertible, $(\mathbb{I}-A)$ is invertible, therefore $S$ is invertible. Please do inform me if there is a mistake.

Comment: It's correct. isn't it? I never thought of using the fact that $I-A$ is invertible whenever $||A|| < 1$. That was a wonderful question though. I'm up voting you because you kept me occupied for about an hour!

Comment: Looks good to me.  You might post your comment as an answer so that the question can be closed.